# getAttribute("value") returning null value, why?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My code is

```
String OTP = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='otp']")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(OTP);
```

Comment: Please add more details so people can help you.

Comment: can you post the html?  `<span>` doesn't typically have a `value` attribute like `<span value="foo">` but it may contain content.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to get the text in the span. `getAttribute("value")` only works for textbox, textarea. For span div and others use `getText()`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='otp']")).getText();
```

Comment: I also used the getText() but then its returning/printing  "Loading.."

Comment: @Sujit Then you will have to put in a wait for the text to change in the span or just as a hack add in a sleep to check. How about adding the relevant html source to your question?

Comment: CSS for my text value is                                                                                                    <span id="otp" class="property-value" style="font-size:48px;color:#F00">

    708962